# How to protect/encrypt R objects in RData files due to EU-GDPR

Tags: r, encryption, rdata

I want to protect the content of my `RData` files with a strong encryption algorithm
since they may contain sensitive personal data which must not be
disclosed due to (legal) EU-GDPR requirements.

How can I do this from within R?

I want to avoid a second manual step to encrypt the `RData` files after creating them to minimize the risk of forgetting it or overlooking any `RData` files.

I am working with Windows in this scenario...

Comment: Maybe you should talk to a lawyer first, to make sure you actually have to do this, before you ask how to do it.

Comment: GDPR doesn't care about encryption. It cares if you store the data or not, for what purpose and how long. If you can decrypt the data, it means you have the data.

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned GDPR since the legal and compliance side is clarified in my case. BTW: Article 32 ("security of processing") states that *"the processor... shall implement appropriate technical... measures to ensure a level of security... inter alia... encryption of personal data..."*

Comment: That doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
library(openssl)

x <- serialize(list(1,2,3), NULL)

passphrase <- charToRaw("This is super secret")
key <- sha256(passphrase)

encrypted_x <- aes_cbc_encrypt(x, key = key)

saveRDS(encrypted_x, "secret-x.rds")

encrypted_y <- readRDS("secret-x.rds")

y <- unserialize(aes_cbc_decrypt(encrypted_y, key = key))
```

You need to deal with secrets management (i.e. the key) but this general idiom should work (with a tad more bulletproofing).

Comment: Good code snippet! I wanted to avoid encrypting my objects before saving them but R does not offer this in base I have still not found a package that offers a single function for that. I am sure, your solution is working (esp. in combination with the package `secret` to store the password: https://cran.r-project.org/package=secret).

Comment: Aye. There's not base serialize but you could write a wrapper for `saveRDS()` which you could put into a locally sourced package.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very late but checkout this package endecrypt

Installation :

```
devtools::install_github("RevanthNemani\endecrypt")
```

Use the following functions for column encryption:

```
airquality <- EncryptDf(x = airquality, pub.key = pubkey, encryption.type = "aes256")
```

For column decryption:

```
airquality <- DecryptDf(x = airquality, prv.key = prvkey, encryption.type = "aes256")
```

Checkout this [Github page](https://github.com/RevanthNemani/endecrypt)

Just remember to generate your keys and save it for first use. Load the keys when required and supply the key object to the functions.

Eg

```
SaveGenKey(bits = 2048,
              private.key.path = "Encription/private.pem",
              public.key.path = "Encription/public.pem")

# Load keys already stored using this function 
prvkey <- LoadKey(key.path = "Encription/private.pem", Private = T)
```

It is very easy to use and your dataframes can be stored in a database or Rdata file.

Answer (score 1):

Using **hrbrmstr** answer I made a simple code snippet of two functions: `saveRDSEnc` and `readRDSEnc`.

If object's size is big it is much better to save the object first, load saved content as `raw` object, encrypt it and then save encrypted content without compression. Code below is using this fact.

```
library(openssl)

###
#' Serialization Interface for Single Objects with encryption
#' 
#' @details Function to write a single R object to a file with encryption using
#'  symmetric AES encryption
#'
#' @param ... arguments passed to saveRDS function
#' @param password Encryption password
#'
#' @return NULL
#' @export
#' 
#' @example
#' x <- "Hello world!"
#' saveRDSEnc(x, file='test.rds', compress='xz', password='1234')
###
saveRDSEnc <- function(..., password) {
  stopifnot("Missing password!" = !missing(password))
  
  args <- list(...)
  key <- openssl::sha256(charToRaw(as.character(password)))
  saveRDS(...)
  
  x <- readBin(con = args$file, what = raw(), n = file.size(args$file))
  x <- openssl::aes_cbc_encrypt(data = x, key = key)
  saveRDS(object = x, file = args$file, compress = FALSE)
  
  invisible(NULL)
}

###
#' Serialization Interface for Single Objects with encryption
#'
#' @details Function to read a single R object from an ecrypted file using
#'  symmetric AES decryption.
#'
#' @param ... arguments passed to readRDS function
#' @param password Decryption password 
#'
#' @return Restored object
#' @export
#' 
#' @example
#' x <- readRDSEnc('test.rds', password='1234')
#' print(x) # Hello world!
###
readRDSEnc <- function(..., password) {
  stopifnot("Missing password!" = !missing(password))
  
  args <- list(...)
  key <- openssl::sha256(charToRaw(as.character(password)))
  tmpf <- tempfile()
  
  tryCatch({
    x <- readRDS(...)
    x <- openssl::aes_cbc_decrypt(data = x, key = key)
    writeBin(object = x, con = tmpf)
    args$file <- tmpf
    x <- do.call(readRDS, args)
  }, finally = unlink(tmpf))

  x
}
```

Comment: THX for your code snippet. Please note that saving the unencrypted data in a file first was what I wanted to avoid and e.g. journaling file systems could even allow to recover the unencrypted data file after "overwriting" it with the encrypted version. Also: After writing the unencrypted file but before overwriting it with the encrypted version an error may occur leaving the unencrypted data file on the disk.